# How can I allow a user to input individual list items into a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create records in the easiest way possible to allow users to input items into a list, which is stored in a bigger list of lists, everything works when manually coded in just not when run as a prompt taking inputs from the user

```
myitems = [[1,"Item1",100,0],[2,"Item2",150,0],[3,"Item3",75,0],[4,"Item4",20,0],[5,"Item5",15,0]]

def printall():
    for x in myitems: 
        print (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6])

def new():
    userinput = input("New?:")
    if userinput == "y":
        userinput = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
        myitems.append(userinput[0])
        userinput = input("Please enter a name:")
        myitems.append(userinput[1])
```

As you can see, I coded in 5 records directly and I'm trying to allow the user to append new ones to myitems however I cannot figure out how to allow them to append individual items into a list, and then have it stored alongside other lists

Comment: before you append it directly to the list `myitems` > `myitems.append(userinput[0])`, take all the inputs from the user and store them in a `templist` and then append that `templist` into `myitems`

Comment: `userinput[0]` this is wronggggg

Comment: Printall is printing too many items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the simplet way:

```
myitems = [[1, "Item1", 100, 0], [2, "Item2", 150, 0], [3, "Item3", 75, 0], [4, "Item4", 20, 0], [5, "Item5", 15, 0]]

def printall():
    for x in myitems:
        print(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])

def new():
    userinput = input("New?:")
    if userinput == "y":
        new = []
        userinput = int(input("Please enter first number:"))
        new.append(userinput)
        userinput = input("Please enter a name:")
        new.append(userinput)
        userinput = int(input("Please enter second number:"))
        new.append(userinput)
        userinput = int(input("Please enter second number:"))
        new.append(userinput)
        myitems.append(new)

new()
printall()
```

Answer (score 2):

Moving froward from the comments in the original question:

```
myitems = [[1,"Item1",100,0],[2,"Item2",150,0],[3,"Item3",75,0],[4,"Item4",20,0],[5,"Item5",15,0]]
tempList = []

# Function print_all

def printall():
    for x in myitems:
        print(*x)       

# Function new()

def new():
    userinput = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
    tempList.append(userinput)

    userinput = input("Please enter a name:")
    tempList.append(userinput)

    myitems.append(tempList[:])
    tempList.clear()
    printall()

# Calling the function
new()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Please enter a number:6
Please enter a name:item6
1 Item1 100 0
2 Item2 150 0
3 Item3 75 0
4 Item4 20 0
5 Item5 15 0
6 item6
```

Comment: If you don't resey templist somehow, you will have a bad time.

Comment: Try appending two items with this code to see whatI mean

Comment: @MadPhysicist noted and amended.

Comment: Please don't post console output as a screenshot. Use a code block instead. Then post a run that appends two entries to the list (call new twice). Your code is still broken.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Fixed it.

Comment: You still have a screenshot

Comment: But yes, you are now making a copy of templist. At the same time, your indentation appears to have gotten messed up, and your printall function prints each item in an entry on a separate line. Try `for x in myitems: print(*x)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist too much of caffeine for the day!

Comment: I understand. Could you please remove the screenshot and replace it with text please?

Answer (score 2):

Your code was really hard to grasp, so I just rewrote so that you can get the gist of it:

```
items = []

def add_items():
  number = int(input("Number: "))
  name = input("Name: ")
  items.append([name, number])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  while input("New?") == "y":
    add_items()
  print(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is so much stuff wrong in your code. `pritall` function is printing too many items, items that are not in the `myitems` list. This is done so that you iterate through the list and print every element you ran into. Another thing, when you want to append something to a list of lists, the type of data you are appending has to be a list. So, you should collect the user input and make a list from it. Then append that list to a list of lists.

What you want is this:

```
myitems = [[1,"Item1",100,0],[2,"Item2",150,0],[3,"Item3",75,0],[4,"Item4",20,0],[5,"Item5",15,0]]

def printall():
    for x in myitems: 
        print(x)

def new():
    userinput = input("New?:")
    if userinput == "y":
        userinput_number = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
        userinput_name = input("Please enter a name:")
        entry = [len(myitems), userinput_number, userinput_name, 0]
        myitems.append(entry)
```

Comment: Is this ok with you? I posted a code from which everything that is wrong with the original code can be seen, but now I added the textual explanations.

Comment: You're right that the printall function is printing too many things, I edited it down for this post however later on, I will need to modify it to print specific index values only which is why I set it up like that.

Comment: You can pass the indices as an arguments to the `printall` function. But I would suggest changing the name haha